# How to find a surface given its tangent plane and a point?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, tangent-spaces

I have the equation for a tangent plant to a surface at the point (a, b, c) but I do not know how I could find an equation for such a surface.

Comment: That will only give you the normal to the surface at that  point. You need more information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Clearly the plane itself and an appropriate sphere could be the surface. And many other surfaces could be used. This is similar to trying to determine the curve in the plane when you only know its tangent at a single point.